# Update Postgres-12.2 to Postgres-12.8

Tags: postgresql

OS version: RHEL 7.9

I want to update Postgresql minor version.
I have Postgres-12.2 installed using source build in /mypath/bin directory. I can't update that Postgres-12.2 using source for some reason.

I have now installed Postgres-12.8 on this server on the default location `/usr/pgsql-12/bin` directory using rpms.

Is it ok to start the database cluster running on v12.2 with Postgres-12.8 `pg_ctl` binary? Is there any harm doing that? Or what precautions do I need to take care of?

Comment: Yes, that's OK. Upgrading minor releases typically don't need "migration steps"

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine, unless you configured your manually built PostgreSQL with some option that renders it incompatible with the binary packages, like `--with-blocksize=<something other than 8k>`.

There are other corner cases, like one installation using `--with-system-tzdata`, and the other using the time zone definitions shipped with PostgreSQL, so that differences in the definitions could change the behavior of `timestamp with time zone`.

Very likely you will be fine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Laurenz